# Error in VisualStudio PackageManagerConsole?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have a C# project with multiple nuget dependencies in VS2017. now I want to restrict version update of certain nugets, so I changed my project file as follow:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="[1.1.1, 2.0.0)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization" Version="[1.1.2, 2.0.0)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This work as expected when I work with '*Manage NuGet Packages*', but when I use **PackageManagerConsole** it will ignore my version restriction and try to load version '2.0.0' of the package!

Also if I update my package using *Manage NuGet Packages*, my package will be updated to correct version (1.1.2 at the moment) but it will override my restriction and then project try to update to version '2.0.0'.

Can anyone tell me how I should update my nuget with **PackageManagerConsole** and keep my version restriction??

Comment: Check to see whether you May you a reference defined in another place e.g. Web/app config?

Comment: Perhaps you have defined references on project and solution level, perhaps some override occurs? Which version of nuget is installed?
Your version restriction for `Abstractions` should only install `Accepts 1.1.1 up to 1.9.x, but not 2.0 and higher`

Comment: @Legends that's the case when I use *Nuget Manager Console*, it only offer version 1.x and not 2.0, but after I update the solution to version 1.2, it will override my version restriction and offer version 2.0. and also **PackageManageConsole** completely ignore my version restriction